# Elements behind react-native modal are not clickable

Tags: javascript, react-native

little confusion here. I created a modal component, and I call that modal in container (parent). Here I struggle to make the other components in the container (parent) clickable when my modal is popping up.

I have set my modal height and width:

```
<Modal transparent={false}
       visible={this.state.isVisible}
       onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>
  <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 300}}>
      ...
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

But it just still doesn't works. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats how it is suppose to work! `modal` from react-native fills the hole screen even if you put height and width, only the view inside has that size the modal is fullscreen. To solve this you can create a modal of your own. just create a component with position absolute and call it in you parent.

```
{this.state.isVisible?<ModalComponent />:null}
```